# Import picture from assets from an object

Tags: react-native

i am currently trying to import an image from my assets in an object of multiple values, here is my object, i can easily see the picture with https, however when i import from the assets folder, nothing appears.

Here is my code:

```
new Meal(
    'm2',
    ['c2'],
    'Toast Hawaii',
    'affordable',
    'one',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/11/21/51/toast-3532016_1280.jpg',
    10,
  )
```

And i am currently trying to get the images from my asset folder:

```
new Meal(
    'm2',
    ['c2'],
    'Toast Hawaii',
    'affordable',
    'one',
    require('../assets/images/picture.jpg'),
    10,
  )
```

However the latter does not work,
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would post the picture somewhere on the web such as https://imgur.com/ then use the imgur url in your object

Answer (score 0):

That just means you most likely have the wrong relative path to your assets folder.  If you need help getting the correct relative path I will need pictures of your folder hierarchy for the project. Also I am pretty sure you aren't supposed to use require for images so you should probably just be putting the path to your assets folder there, not requiring the path to the assets folder.